# Handle cancelled IAP transactions

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm using StoreKit for in-app purchases. I'm finding that the API is quirky in its behavior when the user presses the "Cancel" button.

For example, if I push Cancel on the "Confirm Your In App Purchase" screen, I get a `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` transaction with `error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled` as I'd expect.

But if I push Buy and then press Cancel, I get a `Failed` transaction with `error.code == 0`. The `error.localizedDescription` is "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" which is clearly a lie.

It's tempting to treat all `Failed` transactions as ignorable cancellations, but I can also clearly see that if the device is offline in airplane mode, I get a `Failed` transaction with no alert popup; I should really notify the user to explain the problem in that case.

I note that [MKStoreKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit) assumes all failures are cancellations. `MKStoreManager`'s [`failedTransaction`](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/blob/master/MKStoreObserver.m) method is never called; `MKStoreObserver` always calls `transactionCanceled` for all `Failed` transactions. The `MKStoreManager.h` comments [recommend no error message](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/blob/master/MKStoreManager.h#L53) for `transactionCanceled`, which makes sense, but then who will notify the user about `Failed` non-cancelled transactions?

What's the best practice for handling these failures? Should I swallow errors? Always show an error, even if it's redundant?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have a pretty substantial user base buying stuff over mobile connections and only show alerts for

```
code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled && code != SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed
```

Apparently, it's the best you can do. I've also seen the weird behavior on cancellation that you mention, which is a framework bug as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is pretty close. MKStoreKit can automatically show error messages for valid error conditions like parental control turned on and such that.

Despite that, to handle purchase cancellations, I've also provided a delegate (starting from v3.5) called transactionCanceled in MKStoreKitDelegate.

Handle that and stop any activity spinners or progress hud on the view controller that makes the purchase call...

Comment: MKStoreKit 3.5 doesn't distinguish between failures and cancellations. I've logged an issue on github https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/issues/3 and I've fixed it in my fork.

Comment: Thanks! I've merged your pull request

Comment: Now that my pull request is merged, the latest MKStoreKit automatically shows an error on failures, then calls transactionCanceled on the delegate so users can hide the spinner.

Comment: @Mugunth Why u are not describing non renewable subscriptions anywhere,I saw so many questions regarding this has been kept unanswerd  why?

Comment: non-renewable subscriptions are not different from Non-consumables from a programmer's point of view. If you are using MKStoreKit, you should add your non-renewable subscriptions as a non-consumable and enable server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that errors due to no internet connection should mostly be caught prior to any transaction using Apple's Reachability class IMO. This way you don't need to rely on Apple's API for a straight forward and common kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your responsibility and decision to where show the alert for cancelled transaction or not. But you should definitely finish it, otherwise it'll drop to Failed all the time. So should be something like this:

```
if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
} else {
    [self notifyError:transaction.error];
}
```

UPDATE:
Due to [The Business of iPhone App Development: Making and Marketing Apps that Succeed](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=gebdTqLjj5EC&pg=PA174) we should finish transaction after any update to Failed state. Would be interesting to know if there are situations when we shouldn't.

Answer (score -1):

Still have a one issue...
After clicking on Buy button it will show another Alert view and  ask about Account information.

if i did cancel there then it will goes into case SKErrorUnknown:
then 
**i cant show message like this 
"Your purchase could not be completed. Please check your network settings and try again later."**

```
- (void) failedTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{   
    switch (transaction.error.code) {
        case SKErrorUnknown:
            NSLog(@"SKErrorUnknown");
            break;
        case SKErrorClientInvalid:
            NSLog(@"SKErrorClientInvalid");
            break;
        case SKErrorPaymentCancelled:
            NSLog(@"SKErrorPaymentCancelled");
        break;
        case SKErrorPaymentInvalid:
            NSLog(@"SKErrorPaymentInvalid");
            break;
        case SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed:
            NSLog(@"SKErrorPaymentNotAllowed");
        break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"No Match Found for error");
            break;
    }
    NSLog(@"transaction.error.code %@",[transaction.error description]);
    if (transaction.error.code == SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
        [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] transactionCanceled:transaction];
    } else {
        [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] failedTransaction:transaction];
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction]; 
}
```