# Best way to cancel an SKDownload

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

If my apps user cancels a download, I don't want to corresponding purchase to succeed. Is there someway to tell StoreKit to cancel a purchase that is in progress so that it does not show the alert that says "purchase was successful"?

Answer (score 1):

If by tapping "cancel" you mean The user taps on a cancel button inside your app, According to the [SKPaymentQueue Class Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/addPayment:), There is no way to cancel a purchase that has been set in motion.

But, the user can tap the cancel button on the `Confirm Your In App Purchase` screen, which you can [handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788507/handle-cancelled-iap-transactions) to update your UI accordingly

Comment: I do mean a cancel button inside my app. I am thinking of the time after accepting a purchase but when a download is in progress. I will accept your answer in a day or two if nothing better shows up :-)

Comment: have you looked at the [`cancelDownloads:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/cancelDownloads:) method?

Comment: yes, but it does not stop the purchase from succeeding!